# What is the use of Euler paths?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

In real life what are the use cases of Euler paths ?

> A path in a multigraph $G$ that includes exactly once all the edges of $G$ and has different first and last vertices is called an Euler path. If this path has the same initial and terminal vertices, we call it an Euler circuit.

Comment: Why couldn't you just type the definition?

Comment: Using mobile phone. Gave up the laptop 2 years ago. Screenshots are much easier

Comment: Postman's round.

Comment: The car that takes the photos for google street view ideally drives in an euler path.

Comment: In real life, what is the use of Beethoven's Fifth Symphony? In real life, what is the use of the Mona Lisa?

Comment: Screenshots for things you could just type are not acceptable. You should type the question (otherwise, the search engines cannot search through them).

Comment: @yves postmans round was an Euler circuit i thought

Comment: @loreno would euler path or circuit make a difference for google street view ?

Comment: Besides search-engines there is also the question of accessibility and the question of bandwidth to name but some of the reasons. Please change your  practice.

Comment: @Quid agree on the point when we are using a desktop or a laptop but too hard at mobile. Will try samsungs ocr ... not to be ocd

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin: the postman returns home directly without dropping by the office.

Comment: If we need to visit each place once but visiting it multiple times would serve no purpose.

Comment: @yves maybe for a contractor postman where he goes home after delivery

Comment: DNA fragment assembly : https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDgQFjAEahUKEwj9g8jq89XHAhVKGj4KHaciCGU&url=http%3A%2F%2Facademics.smcvt.edu%2Fjellis-monaghan%2FStudent%2520Research%2FKaptcianos.ppt&ei=MKPlVf2rG8q0-AGnxaCoBg&usg=AFQjCNHPEdtzzQy5oV1JXHLT_csLl1wXEA&sig2=pU7ZlWEv4UTTsiSSzLZCLg

Comment: Here is a link of Euler paths used in integrated circuits design: 
http://www.ohio.edu/people/starzykj/webcad/ee415/VLSI/design/stick/stick.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eulerian trails are used in bioinformatics to reconstruct the **DNA sequence** from its fragments.[12] They are also used in **CMOS circuit design** to find an optimal logic gate ordering.[13]

Reference
Eulerian_path, Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path